# PG: How to show total count for this query if result is 0

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a postgres 9.6 table called `selected_media`, with a column called `_type` that is set to either `book` or `movie`.

I want to select the `COUNT` of each type, in 1 single row, like this:

`25 | 715`

To do this, I have this query:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'book'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS books_count,
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'movie' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS movies_count
FROM selected_media
WHERE subscriber_id = $1
```

The problem is 2 fold:

1. I want each column to show the respective **total count for that _type only** if the sum in that column happens to be 0 (none selected). This is because the UI/UX states *"selecting 0 books or movies is the same as selecting all of them"*.
2. It needs to be fast, this table will have millions of rows in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then do it slightly different, use the (more or less) *complementary* of `COALESCE`, which is [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(books_count, 0) AS books_count,
    NULLIF(movies_count, 0) AS movies_count
FROM
    ( -- Original, slightly simplified query
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'book'  THEN 1 END) AS books_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'movie' THEN 1 END) AS movies_count
    FROM 
        selected_media
    WHERE 
        subscriber_id = 1234
    ) AS s1 ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=74eed0c220b6b8f2fec49085f62776c3)*

If you don't want to have a NULL value when the result is zero, but another one, you can use:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN books_count <> 0 THEN books_count 
    ELSE (another_value_or_expression_for_books) 
    END  AS books_count,
    CASE 
    WHEN movies_count <> 0 THEN movies_count 
    ELSE (another_value_or_expression_for_movies) 
    END  AS movies_count
FROM
    ( -- Original, slightly simplified query
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'book'  THEN 1 END) AS books_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN _type = 'movie' THEN 1 END) AS movies_count
    FROM 
        selected_media
    WHERE 
        subscriber_id = 1234
    ) AS s1 ;
```

You can also use `count(case ...)` instead of `SUM`, and, in latest versions of PostgreSQL, you can use a [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), instead of `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(books_count, 0) AS books_count,
    NULLIF(movies_count, 0) AS movies_count
FROM
    (SELECT
        count(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'book') AS books_count,
        count(*) FILTER (WHERE _type = 'movie') AS movies_count
    FROM 
        selected_media
    WHERE 
        subscriber_id = 1234
    ) AS s1 ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ed66b5d28f3325f2a4bcbf53f2c01351)*

---

If you need the fastest possible speed, and depending on the number of _types, and the number of elements of each type, you could use some partial indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_books ON selected_media (subscriber_id) WHERE _type='book' ;
CREATE INDEX idx_movies ON selected_media (subscriber_id) WHERE _type='movie' ;
```

And then perform your query as two subqueries:

```
SELECT
    nullif( (select count(*) from selected_media where _type='book'  
             and subscriber_id = 1234), 
           0) AS count_books,
    nullif( (select count(*) from selected_media where _type='movie'  
             and subscriber_id = 1234), 
           0) AS count_movies ;
```

This will give you a query plan doing two *index only scans* most of the time.

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                    |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| Result  (cost=164.10..164.12 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=1.491..1.492 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                       |
|   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                                                     |
|     ->  Aggregate  (cost=159.94..159.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.485..1.485 rows=1 loops=1)                                                             |
|           ->  Index Only Scan using idx_books on selected_media  (cost=0.28..150.36 rows=3833 width=0) (actual time=0.016..1.108 rows=3974 loops=1)           |
|                 Index Cond: (subscriber_id = 1234)                                                                                                            |
|                 Heap Fetches: 3974                                                                                                                            |
|   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)                                                                                                                                     |
|     ->  Aggregate  (cost=4.15..4.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                 |
|           ->  Index Only Scan using idx_movies on selected_media selected_media_1  (cost=0.12..4.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1) |
|                 Index Cond: (subscriber_id = 1234)                                                                                                            |
|                 Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                                               |
| Planning time: 0.094 ms                                                                                                                                       |
| Execution time: 1.514 ms                                                                                                                                      |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=29ad5d01d9dcee8f9a191fa23f268cfa)*

---

If you have very many `_type`, or you want your query to work with any possible `_type` (and not two specifically chosen) your second choice would be to have the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_subscriber_type ON selected_media (subscriber_id, _type) ;
```

... then, the previous query will execute using this index

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                         |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Result  (cost=1643.07..1643.09 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.679..0.680 rows=1 loops=1)                                                          |
|   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                                          |
|     ->  Aggregate  (cost=821.53..821.54 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.670..0.671 rows=1 loops=1)                                                  |
|           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on selected_media  (cost=29.98..819.19 rows=933 width=0) (actual time=0.170..0.573 rows=992 loops=1)                |
|                 Recheck Cond: ((subscriber_id = 1234) AND (_type = 'book'::text))                                                                  |
|                 Heap Blocks: exact=547                                                                                                             |
|                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_subscriber_type  (cost=0.00..29.75 rows=933 width=0) (actual time=0.113..0.113 rows=992 loops=1)      |
|                       Index Cond: ((subscriber_id = 1234) AND (_type = 'book'::text))                                                              |
|   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)                                                                                                                          |
|     ->  Aggregate  (cost=821.53..821.54 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)                                                  |
|           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on selected_media selected_media_1  (cost=29.98..819.19 rows=933 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
|                 Recheck Cond: ((subscriber_id = 1234) AND (_type = 'movie'::text))                                                                 |
|                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_subscriber_type  (cost=0.00..29.75 rows=933 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)        |
|                       Index Cond: ((subscriber_id = 1234) AND (_type = 'movie'::text))                                                             |
| Planning time: 0.077 ms                                                                                                                            |
| Execution time: 0.706 ms                                                                                                                           |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=43d779a50c2476bb94d5e0b8f5040cfe)*

Comment: This seems to be a great refactoring of my query, but I still need to do point #1 above (sorry I didn't explain it clearly). If the answer is 0 (or null in your case) then it needs to show the total count of from the `media` table (regardless of type) (`select count(*) from media`). So say theres 0 books but 12 movies, it should show `500 | 12` (if theres 500 total media records)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. In that case, change this slightly: use `case when ... = 0 then (select count(*) from media) else ... end`

Comment: Thanks so much, this is an incredible answer. I <3 this stack exchange.